# ¿Dónde está el error en mi código?

Tags: php, mysql, visual-studio

intento crear una base de datos con visual studio code, desde un fichero php a una base de datos mysql. Uso XAMPP con MySQL y el error de la web es el siguiente:

Conexion exitosa

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exec() on string in C:\www\Minuevoophp\createdb.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\www\Minuevoophp\createdb.php on line 17

Eso me aparece en el navegador al ejecutar este código:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //servidor
$db = "proyecto"; //base de datos
$user = "gestor"; //usuario
$pass = "secreto"; //contraseña
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4";
try{
//instanciamos el objeto PDO
 $bd = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
 //asignamos los atributos del objeto a nuestra variable base de datos.
 $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo "<strong>Conexion exitosa</strong><br>";
$bd="CREATE DATABASE myBDPDO "
 . "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
//usamos el método exec() porque no devuelve resultado
$bd->exec($sql);

 echo "<strong>Base de datos creada exitosamente</strong><br>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Fallo de conexión" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Necesito ayuda, no puedo continuar con mis ejercicios y mi profesora no ve el error. Un abrazo.

Comment: La variable $sql no existe, en todo caso asignaste a $bd el query y debería ser asignado a $sql. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

El problema esta en:

```
$bd="CREATE DATABASE myBDPDO "
 . "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
//usamos el método exec() porque no devuelve resultado
$bd->exec($sql);
```

Intenta corregir la variable para el query de `$bd` a `$sql`, tu consulta corregida podría ser:

```
$sql="CREATE DATABASE myBDPDO "
 . "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
//usamos el método exec() porque no devuelve resultado
$bd->exec($sql);
```

Me inspire en la respuesta a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232901/pdo-creating-database-and-tables) espero te pueda servir.